# Parallel Calculation of Distance Correlation (dcor) from DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing

I have a pandas DataFrame with 50 rows and 22000 columns, and I would like to calculate a distance correlation (dcor package) between each pair of columns. The code that I created (with a serial-processing and a portion of the data) is:

```
import pandas as pd
import dcor

DF = pd.DataFrame({'X':[0.72,-0.25,-1.2,-3],'Y':[-0.128,0.2,2,5.6],'Z':[15,-0.425,-0.3,-5]})

DCOR_REZ=pd.DataFrame(index=['X','Y','Z'],columns=['X','Y','Z'])
col_names=DCOR_REZ.columns.tolist()
k=0
for i in col_names:

    v1=DF.loc[:,i].as_matrix()
    for j in col_names[k:]:

        v2=DF.loc[:,j].as_matrix()
        rez=dcor.distance_correlation(v1,v2)
        DCOR_REZ.at[i,j]=rez
        DCOR_REZ.at[j,i]=rez

    k=k+1

print DCOR_REZ

         X        Y        Z
X        1 0.981778 0.854349
Y 0.981778        1 0.726328
Z 0.854349 0.726328        1
```

**To execute this code on a full DataFrame I need 21h!**.

Since my server has **40 processors** I was thinking to cut the time by 40 and get the results in ~30 minutes but **I don't know how to rewrite this code for parallel processing**.

How can I rewrite the code?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the creator of the dcor package. One problem of this approach is that the pairwise distance matrices for each column are computed on each iteration, instead of just once. If you have enough memory, you could compute those matrices beforehand, and then compute the distance correlation:

```
import pandas as pd
import dcor
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

DF = pd.DataFrame({'X':[0.72,-0.25,-1.2,-3],'Y':[-0.128,0.2,2,5.6],'Z':[15,-0.425,-0.3,-5]})

DCOR_REZ=pd.DataFrame(index=['X','Y','Z'],columns=['X','Y','Z'])
col_names=DCOR_REZ.columns.tolist()
k=0

dict_centered_matrices = {}

def compute_matrix(i):
    v1=DF.loc[:,i].as_matrix()

    v1_dist = squareform(pdist(v1[:, np.newaxis]))
    return (i, dcor.double_centered(v1_dist))

dict_centered_matrices = dict(map(compute_matrix, col_names))

for i in col_names:

    v1_centered = dict_centered_matrices[i]

    for j in col_names[k:]:

        v2_centered = dict_centered_matrices[j]

        rez=np.sqrt(
               dcor.average_product(v1_centered, v2_centered)/np.sqrt(
                                 dcor.average_product(v1_centered, v1_centered)*
                                 dcor.average_product(v2_centered, v2_centered)))

        DCOR_REZ.at[i,j]=rez
        DCOR_REZ.at[j,i]=rez

    k=k+1

print(DCOR_REZ)
```

This should make your code faster, at the expense of consuming more memory. I will consider adding convenience functions for this case, as it seems a common one. You can also try parallelizing the code using the multiprocessing module, and replacing the map function with the map method of a Pool instance.

Answer (score 2):

Since dcor version 0.5 I have added a [`rowwise`](https://dcor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/dcor.rowwise.html#dcor.rowwise) method with this explicit purpose in mind. It will parallelize the computation using available cores when the right conditions are met (basically, when the distance covariance/correlation is computed between random variables and not random vectors, by default). Sorry for the delay in implementing this.

Comment: Could you add an example that demonstrates how to apply `rowwise` in this case  ( distance correlation between each pair of columns)? The documentation only shows examples with two different arrays.

Comment: It would also be nice to see an example of how to calculate with `rowwise` the pvalue for said distance correlation using `dcor.independence.distance_covariance_test` (i.e. how to pass the arguments `exponent` and `num_resamples`)